# Check CSS selector with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I've try to code a function which can select element in the shortest way, here's my regex:

`/^(\w+)?(\S)(\w\S+)$/gi`

Here's my Code

```
function getEl(selector){
    if(typeof selector === 'string'){
      var match = null;
      var regex = /^(\w+)?(\S)(\w\S+)$/gi;
      match = regex.exec(selector);
      if(match){
        if(match[1]){
          selector = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(match[0]))
        }else{
          if(match[2] && match[2] === "#"){
            selector = document.getElementById(match[3])
          }else if(match[2] === "."){
            selector = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName(match[3]))
          }else{
            selector = document.getElementsByTagName(match[3])
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return selector
  }
```

The code that i wrote just only check once [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsST.png)

I want it to be like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RxuC.png)

Comment: Is this what you meant to do?
https://regex101.com/r/v2vgmi/1

Comment: Could you give examples of matches an non-matches. And please include them in your question, not as links.

Comment: @Kamuffel i'm check #id and .class and css selector like div#selector

Comment: the problem have sovled